# Rest overrides GlobalStyle

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

Im doing two files to apply some Style to my application, one contains the Reset CSS, and the other some CSS to apply to all others page, and routing w/ `_app.jsx`. But the Reset Css are overwriting my GlobalStyle (the margin in may case).

My `_app.jsx` code:

```
import GlobalStyle from "@/theme/GlobalStyle";
import ResetCss from "@/theme/resetcss";

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <>
            <ResetCss />
            <GlobalStyle />
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </>
    )
}
```

My `GlobalStyle.jsx code:

```
const { default: styled, createGlobalStyle } = require("styled-components");

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
    body {
        background-color: #051D3B;
        width: 100VW;
        margin: 40px;
}
`

export default GlobalStyle
```

Im expect a solution to the overwriting problem, how can i use two style files, but the `GlobalStyle.jsx` overwrite the `ResetCss.jsx` style.